# Pyside client and server

Tags: python, networking, pyside, raspberry-pi

I just start learning python to work with raspberry, my ultimate goal is to make a client / server application by creating a p2p network between raspberry. I chose to use the library asyncore to make client and server and initially pygame for graphics, now I'm trying to use PySide but I have a problem.

How can I integrate the asyncore.loop() into the main loop of pyside?

Comment: I guess you can put asyncore to a separate thread. So you will have 2 loops in parallel. What exactly do you need asyncore for? Why can't you do that with pyside?

Comment: I want every raspberry can communicate to others to change what displays on the screen.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do take advice

Comment: You can separate pyside and asyncore into 2 programs, and make some kind of communication between them (ipc). Network p2p daemon with asyncore, and GUI client with pyside.

Comment: You should look into twisted.  http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
class ClientThread(threading.Thread):

# Start the thread for the socket
def __init__(self, server, port, user, gui):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.client = ClientConnection(server, int(port), user, gui)

# Run the asyncore loop
def run(self):
    try:
        asyncore.loop()
    except:
        return 0
```

Maybe it can be usefull for you this example: 
https://github.com/absolution/Month-2--Chat-Client-/blob/master/ClientGUI.py